# ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(962) handshake failed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

i'm trying to run my project(that I written it on my macBook) on my windows server.it use selenium and chrome web driver -v 87
when its run it opens web driver and start browsing and clicking but it doesn't catch anything and just print a writing and an repeated error:

```
dev tools listening on ws: //127.0.0.1:51103/devtools/browser/...:[Error:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_win GetBluetoothAdapterStaticsActivationFactory failed: Class not registered
[Error: ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(962)] handshake failed: returned -1, SSL error code 1, ror -100
```

I don't know what should I do.
my program was working correctly on my mac!
do you have any IDEA?
It is not like other similar questions on stack overflow I try them and doesnt work for this Error code.